# Angular: How to handle environment-dependent properties

Tags: angular

Lets say I have an Angular app that requests data from a REST-server.

Today I have a ConfigService that is injected into my RESTClientService.
ConfigServices gives my the properties I need to address the REST-server (e.g. the URL).

If I change to the production environment I need to change the ConfigService because the REST-server has a different URL there.

I can not access a config-file that is put near the angular-built because the app is executed in the users browser and not the server.
And every other information is put static into the files so there is no link to a environments context.

Is there a more elegant way to handle this?

Comment: *And every other information is put static into the files so there is no link to a environments context.* that is not true as environment settings are placed in main*.js and can be changed there AFTER application is built.\

Answer (score 0):

> I can not access a config-file that is put near the angular-built
>   because the app is executed in the users browser and not the server.

Whole application is on client side and still you can place config files on server.... after all, application is server from somewhere right?

You could alternatively put that hot config in REST configuration endpoint and fetch properties on app bootstrap.

Comment: Well, the REST URL is one of my information that change between DEV, TEST and PROD.